# Convert sql statement with two joined count subqueries to Linq-EF6 functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

Having trouble figuring out how to convert the following sql query into Linq, and I'm not really interested in the subcounts, just a proper listing of profiles (multiple columns for hydrating POCO Profile objects) that can be serialized to json.  The client app presents these profiles that need to be moderated and helps the user view and update IsApproved flag.

```
select p.*, p1.g_count, p2.m_count
from profiles p
left join (select profileid,count(*) as g_count from GuestbookEntries ge where ge.IsApproved is null group by profileid having count(*)>0) as p1 on p1.profileid = p.profileid
left join (select profileid,count(*) as m_count from MediaEntries me where me.IsApproved is null group by profileid having count(*)>0) as p2 on p2.profileid = p.profileid
where 1=1
and g_count is not null or m_count is not null
```

What we're doing here is trying to list all profiles that have ANY number of GuestbookEntries with IsApproved=null OR ANY number of MediaEntries with IsApproved=null. Statement works correctly in SQL server, but having trouble figuring out how to convert to LINQ functions/statements that will allow me to layer on additional where clauses for authorization of access to the profiles *(handled correctly in a simpler form of LINQ functions elsewhere)*.

Desired output is a list of Profiles that have count(*) from guestbookentries or mediaentries greater-than 0 and not null

Given the below data, output of query should be (POCO classes):

```
ProfileId ProfileName
--------- -----------
        1 Test1
        2 Test2
        3 Test3
```

The client app updates guestbookentries and mediaentries IsApproved=1 or 0 which moves their state from basically unhandled to handled/approved or handled/not-approved

simplified DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE profiles ( ProfileID int identity(1,1), ProfileName nvarchar(100) )
CREATE TABLE guestbookentries ( ID int identity(1,1), ProfileId int NOT NULL, Comment nvarchar(max), IsApproved bit )
CREATE TABLE mediaentries ( ID int identity(1,1), ProfileId int NOT NULL, Comment nvarchar(max), IsApproved bit )

insert into profiles ( ProfileName ) values ( 'Test1' )
insert into profiles ( ProfileName ) values ( 'Test2' )
insert into profiles ( ProfileName ) values ( 'Test3' )
insert into profiles ( ProfileName ) values ( 'Test4' )
insert into GuestbookEntries ( Comment, ProfileId ) values ( 'Comment', 1 )
insert into GuestbookEntries ( Comment, ProfileId ) values ( 'Comment', 3 )
insert into MediaEntries ( Comment, ProfileId ) values ( 'MediaComment', 2 )
insert into MediaEntries ( Comment, ProfileId ) values ( 'MediaComment', 3 )
```

As a current workaround I'm using `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<type>(sb.ToString())` which of course works, but looking to keep my Profile Authorization codepaths in sync using the LINQ-EF functions.

Here is a NetFiddle already created:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/2iTi7i#&togetherjs=KuDJVdv9EJ

Comment: Please post the desired output also.

Comment: @SelvaTS thanks for commenting.  I added desired output and have added a NetFiddle link for others to fork.

Comment: the desired output profiles should have g_count or m_count, not both? The sample data gives null value in g_count or m_count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query looks complex to me, let's simplify it first. As you do not want the count of tables in the output, but you just need them to see if any rows exists in the child tables (Books and Media) where isApproved is null, then you should always use `EXISTS` instead of `COUNT`. It will be good for performance too. So lets rewrite your query as -

```
select * 
from @profiles as p -- select all profiles
Where exists (select 1  -- where at least one guestbook entry approval is null
              from @GuestbookEntries 
              where ProfileId = p.ProfileID 
                and IsApproved is null)
OR exists (select 1 -- Or at least one media entry approval is null
           from @MediaEntries 
           where ProfileId = p.ProfileID 
             and IsApproved is null)
```

Lets convert this SQL query into LINQ

```
var result = DBContext.Profiles.Where(p => 
                 DBContext.GuestbookEntries
                          .Any(g => g.ProfileId == p.ProfileId && g.IsApproved == null) 
                 || DBContext.MediaEntries
                          .Any(m=> m.ProfileId == p.ProfileId && m.IsApproved == null));
```

Comment: Originally I was trying to get the counts of the child table's entries (where isapproved is null) but now the client is more interested in just the number of profiles that have the child tables with any count of records with isapproved is null, so this query ends up being the correct one.  The simplification wouldn't have worked before but given the simpler req's it does.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
var result = (from pro in context.profiles
              join guest in context.GuestbookEntries
                            .Where(a => a.IsApproved == null)
                            .GroupBy(x => x.profileid)
                            .Where(z => z.Count() > 0)
                            .Select(y => new { ProId = y.profileid, Counts = y.Count() })
              on pro.Id equals guest.ProID into guestBook
              from guestbe in guestBook.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join media in context.MediaEntries
                            .Where(a => a.IsApproved == null)
                            .GroupBy(x => x.profileid)
                            .Where(z => z.Count() > 0)
                            .Select(y => new { ProId = y.profileid, Counts = y.Count() })
              on pro.Id equals media.ProID into mediaEn
              from mediaEnt in mediaEn.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new { pro, GuestCount = guestbe.Counts, MediaCount = mediaEnt.Counts }).ToList();
```